# How can I left-align strings using String.format()?

Tags: java, string, alignment, string.format

I'm using String.format() in Java trying to emulate the printf() control channel available in C. I understand how to specify that a string should be placed in a field which takes 20 characters, 5, 2 ... with 3 decimals, 2, etc.  However, the strings are printed right-aligned in their field.

How do I left-align the strings?

Here's an example of a possible output which I would like to modify to left-align `EXECUTING` and `CREATED` in their fields.

```
Process PID: 25    Status: -----------       EXECUTING
Process PID: 36    Status: READY-SUSPENDED
Process PID:  4    Status: ----------------        CREATED
```

*note: consider '-' as an empty space

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Same way as with printf -- use a `-` modifier in the format

Comment: And if you're using the position specifier, `String.format("%1$-10s", "test")`

Comment: Can you include an example in your answer?

Answer (score 9):

```
System.out.format("%-10d%-32s%-16s%-16s%-32s", obj.getId(), obj.getBname(), obj.getAname(),obj.getLanguage(),obj.getPublication());
```

Just add hyphen `-` in front of the number.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
class F { 
  public static void main( String ... args ) { 
    String [] status =  { "EXECUTING", "READY-SUSPENDED", "CREATED" };
    int [] pids =  {123, 34, 1231 };
    int i = 0;
    for( String s : status ) { 
       System.out.printf("Process PID: %5d Status : %s%n", pids[i++], s);
    }  
  }
}
```

Output:

```
$java F
Process PID:   123 Status : EXECUTING
Process PID:    34 Status : READY-SUSPENDED
Process PID:  1231 Status : CREATED
```

Comment: This isn't left justified, though. That requires the use of the '-'.

Comment: System.out.printf("Process PID: %5d Status : %s\n", pids[i++], s);