# Left-align and right-align lining output?

Tags: java, string-formatting

I'm practicing my Java skills and I'm trying to left-align everything, however, it's not working as I want it to.

Basically I want something like this:

```
         Player:    Jackson
Number of tries:    14
```

And here is what I'm trying:

```
String format1 = "%-30s %30s%n";

String temp = String.format(format1, "Player:", "Jackson");
System.out.print(temp);
temp = String.format(format1, "Number of tries:", "14");
System.out.print(temp);
```

However, the words on the left-hand side don't match up, and the words on the right-hand side don't match up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I left-align strings using String.format()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893313/how-can-i-left-align-strings-using-string-format)

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the `-` in the format.

```
String format1 = "%30s %-30s%n";
```

With your code, this produces the following output:

```
                       Player: Jackson                       
              Number of tries: 14
```

---

You can then improve the formatting from there to get an output closer to your example.

```
String format1 = "%16s    %-30s%n";
```

Which gives:

```
         Player:    Jackson                       
Number of tries:    14
```